# CATALINA_HOME environmental variable is not defined correctly

Tags: tomcat6, catalina

I installed Apache Tomcat 6.0 to a `C:/Program Files` folder and I set the environmental variables `JAVA_HOME` and `CATALINA_HOME`, but when I start the server using `startup.bat`, I am getting the error:

> CATALINA_HOME environmental variable is not defined correctly.

My `CATALINA_HOME` environment variable is set to `CATALINA_HOME=C:\Program Files\apache-tomcat-6.0.35`.

What did I do wrong?

Comment: Well, the first question is whether Tomcat is in `C:\Program Files\apache-tomcat-6.0.35`? In other words, is there a `C:\Program Files\apache-tomcat-6.0.35\bin`, `C:\Program Files\apache-tomcat-6.0.35\wepapps`, `C:\Program Files\apache-tomcat-6.0.35\common`, etc?

Comment: yeah tomcat is in c:\Program Files\apache-tomcat-6.0.35

Comment: After you set the environment variable, did you open a new CMD.EXE window? Windows that existed before you set the variables won't see them, only new windows will.

Answer (score 31):

At first you have to mention tomcat up to tomcat's version refer below

**CATALINA_HOME:  C:\Program Files\apache-tomcat-6.0.35;**
then set CLASSPATH variable to

**CLASSPATH : C:\Program Files\apache-tomcat-6.0.35\lib;**

then finally edit path variable to 
**PATH: .;%CATALINA_HOME%\bin;**

**NOTE:** a semicolon(;) must be put at the end of each and every variable.

Comment: If you add a semicolon to the end of CATALINA_HOME, then try to use that variable in the PATH, you'll end up with `C:\Program Files\apache-tomcat-6.0.35;\bin` and that path won't resolve. In fact, DON'T put a semicolon at the end of each and every variable.

Answer (score 17):

```
set JAVA_HOME :C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_26
CLASSPATH :C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_26\bin
CATALINA_HOME : C:\Program Files\apache-tomcat-6.0.35
```

Answer (score 11):

Make sure you cd your directory on the cmd window to the path where the Tomcat is before you you call the service.bat file

Answer (score 6):

Open up your catalina.bat / catalina.sh .. and check for  CATALINA_HOME , this could have been hardcoded if you have copied Tomcat from somewhere.

Comment: Yes, I found the CATALINA_HOME in my vm was set to another value which does not exist. This answer saved my time. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I have got the same problem, I copied the path location of JRE_HOME

JRE_Home= "C:Progra******** ;"

Here i have entered Semicolon which we should not , I removed it, 
then Tomcat Started successfully .

So Semicolon must be removed at the end after setting path 
JRE_HOME or
JAVA_HOME or
CATALINA_HOME .

Answer (score 2):

You also need to set the JAVA_HOME variable to point to the JDK, not JRE.
Tomcat must know were Java is installed. It needs the JDK.
In the end restart computer.

https://serverfault.com/questions/579159/the-catalina-home-environment-variable-is-not-defined-correctly-this-environment

Answer (score 1):

Please care to remove the semi colon at the end of defining user variables such as JAVA_HOME, CATALINA_HOME

Answer (score 0):

In environment variables define CATALINA_HOME as a new variable and the value for the variable value assign to >>> C:\apache\apache-tomcat-7.0.40

in the path append this %CATALINA_HOME%\bin to get the command "catalina start" to work

Answer (score 0):

Set the 
**CATALINA_HOME : C:\apache-tomcat-9.0.27**
The path of the Tomcat directory (no need to add "bin")
**CLASSPATH : C:\apache-tomcat-9.0.27\lib**

For Windows 10 newer versions, remove the ";" and update each entry to the PATH variable

```
%PATH%;
%JAVA_HOME%\bin;
%CATALINA_HOME%\bin;
%CLASSPATH%\servlet-api.jar;
```