# Error in Java Rest Service : Connection refused: connect

Tags: java, rest, environment-variables

I am trying to create a rest service. But I got the following error after running.

```
Exception in thread "main" com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientHandlerException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at com.sun.jersey.client.urlconnection.URLConnectionClientHandler.handle(URLConnectionClientHandler.java:151)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client.handle(Client.java:648)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource.handle(WebResource.java:680)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource.access$200(WebResource.java:74)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource$Builder.get(WebResource.java:507)
    at astral.restservice.client.Test.main(Test.java:20)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.jersey.client.urlconnection.URLConnectionClientHandler._invoke(URLConnectionClientHandler.java:249)
    at com.sun.jersey.client.urlconnection.URLConnectionClientHandler.handle(URLConnectionClientHandler.java:149)
    ... 5 more
```

Following is my web.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
  <display-name>astral.restservice</display-name>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
      <param-value>astral.restservice</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Hello.java

```
package astral.restservice;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

// Plain old Java Object it does not extend as class or implements 
// an interface

// The class registers its methods for the HTTP GET request using the @GET annotation. 
// Using the @Produces annotation, it defines that it can deliver several MIME types,
// text, XML and HTML. 

// The browser requests per default the HTML MIME type.

//Sets the path to base URL + /hello
@Path("/hello")
public class Hello {

  // This method is called if TEXT_PLAIN is request
  @GET
  @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
  public String sayPlainTextHello() {
    return "Hello Jersey";
  }

  // This method is called if XML is request
  @GET
  @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_XML)
  public String sayXMLHello() {
    return "<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>" + "<hello> Hello Jersey" + "</hello>";
  }

  // This method is called if HTML is request
  @GET
  @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
  public String sayHtmlHello() {
    return "<html> " + "<title>" + "Hello Jersey" + "</title>"
        + "<body><h1>" + "Hello Jersey" + "</body></h1>" + "</html> ";
  }

}
```

Test.java

```
package astral.restservice.client;

import java.net.URI;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.UriBuilder;
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client;
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientResponse;
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource;
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.config.ClientConfig;
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.config.DefaultClientConfig;
public class Test {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    ClientConfig config = new DefaultClientConfig();
    Client client = Client.create(config);
    WebResource service = client.resource(getBaseURI());
    // Fluent interfaces
    System.out.println(service.path("rest").path("hello").accept(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN).get(ClientResponse.class).toString());
    // Get plain text
    System.out.println(service.path("rest").path("hello").accept(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN).get(String.class));
    // Get XML
    System.out.println(service.path("rest").path("hello").accept(MediaType.TEXT_XML).get(String.class));
    // The HTML
    System.out.println(service.path("rest").path("hello").accept(MediaType.TEXT_HTML).get(String.class));


  }

  private static URI getBaseURI() {
    return UriBuilder.fromUri("http://localhost:8080/astral.restservice").build();
  }

}
```

This is my project structure
[image]

Why I am getting this error? Thanks in advance.

I got the following error from browser after run it using tomcat v7

```
HTTP Status 500 - Servlet.init() for servlet Jersey REST Service threw exception

type Exception report

message Servlet.init() for servlet Jersey REST Service threw exception

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet.init() for servlet Jersey REST Service threw exception
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:947)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1009)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

root cause

com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors$ErrorMessagesException
    com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors.processErrorMessages(Errors.java:170)
    com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors.postProcess(Errors.java:136)
    com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors.processWithErrors(Errors.java:199)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.initiate(WebApplicationImpl.java:695)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.initiate(WebApplicationImpl.java:690)
    com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.initiate(ServletContainer.java:438)
    com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer$InternalWebComponent.initiate(ServletContainer.java:287)
    com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.load(WebComponent.java:587)
    com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.init(WebComponent.java:213)
    com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:342)
    com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:516)
    javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:160)
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:947)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1009)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/7.0.39 logs.
Apache Tomcat/7.0.39
```

I tried to run server using command prompt I got the following error,
I set CATALINA_HOME,JAVA_HOME,CLASSPATH and add PATH also.

**

```
D:\apache-tomcat-7.0.39\bin>startup
The CATALINA_HOME environment variable is not defined correctly
This environment variable is needed to run this program

D:\apache-tomcat-7.0.39\bin>startup.bat
The CATALINA_HOME environment variable is not defined correctly
This environment variable is needed to run this program

D:\apache-tomcat-7.0.39\bin>catalina.bat
The CATALINA_HOME environment variable is not defined correctly
This environment variable is needed to run this program

D:\apache-tomcat-7.0.39\bin>
```

**

Comment: Connection refused = the port is not open. Did you start your app server before trying to run your client? Is your app server configured to run on port 8080? Can you hit it with a browser?

Comment: @charlie check the question I edited it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
http://localhost:8080
```

simply access this link from your web browser. I think that your apache server is running on some other port. Please check the properties of server, and replace the port appropriately.

Comment: Please tell me what are you getting in internet explorer or firefox or chrome, not in command prompt.

Comment: oh my bad, i think you need to make sure , u r setting this path correctly. ref: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9361623/catalina-home-environmental-variable-is-not-defined-correctly

Comment: @Parvathy, Please can you let me know how did you resolve this issue? I'm also facing the same issue.. I can access the Rest service from browser, but cannot with a rest client in java...

Comment: @spk my server was running in different port. I set port and it works correctly. Check my conf file

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone looks at this post, check to see how your calling the application

I had:

```
java -jar test-suite.jar -dHost http://localhost:8080 -other params
```

I should have done this:

```
java -dHost http://localhost:8080 -other params -jar test-suite.jar
```

simple mistake, put your params first ahead of -jar

Answer (score 0):

Try to open port. You can do this by :

```
iptables -P INPUT ACCEPT
```

Note : The above commands opens up all ports