# CATALINA_HOME environmental veriable is not defined correctly

Tags: java, tomcat, tomcat6

I've installed Tomcat7, set the systems environmental variables for both JAVA_HOME and CATALINA_HOME. However, when I try and run startup from command prompt I'm getting the following error. 
CATALINA_HOME environmental veriable is not defined correctly.
This environmental variable is needed to run this program.

Here's the command prompt:

[image]

Also I've set the enviromental veriables like this:

[image]

I don't understand why this is happening?

Comment: do you restart command prompt after setting this property?

Comment: Aren't you supposed to point it to the /bin/ folder?

Comment: actually there is answer on this site: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9361623/catalina-home-environmental-variable-is-not-defined-correctly

Comment: Have you added `%CATALINA_HOME%\bin;` to your path?

Comment: `%CATALINA_HOME%` is indeed wrong. It should also include `apache-tomcat-7.0.29`

Answer (score 1):

Guessing from your console, you may want to set CATALINA_HOME to 'C:\JavaSE7\Tomcat7\apache-tomcat-7.0.29'

Answer (score 0):

In command prompt, execute:

```
echo %CATALINA_HOME%
```

Does it show C:\JavaSE7\Tomcat7?  If not, have you restarted your machine since adding the variable? You might have to do that.

Comment: @msangel - thanks for the update, haven't been on a windows machine in a while :)

Answer (score 0):

I fix it this way on command line:

set CATALINA_HOME = C:TomCat7\apache-tomcat-7.0.29
then ran up startup in
TomCat7\apache-tomcat-7.0.29\bin