# The CATALINA_HOME environment variable is not defined correctly when setting up Tomcat 9.0.19

Tags: tomcat, tomcat9

I am having a hard time getting *Tomcat* going can anyone help me with the set-up?

I have downloaded the binary distribution of *tomcat-9.0.19*, unpacked and assigned the environment variable `CATALINA_HOME` to the path of the *tomcat* folder `(C:\Users\User\Downloads\apache-tomcat-9.0.19-windows-x64\apache-tomcat-9.0.19)`

Now when I go to the bin folder and try `"sh startup.sh"`, I get the message `"Unable to start as CATALINA_HOME contains a colon (:) character`
or as for `"./startup.sh"`: The `CATALINA_HOME` environment variable is not defined correctly

How do I get tomcat to start?

I have tried all the replies from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9361623/catalina-home-environmental-variable-is-not-defined-correctly)
but none of those worked for me

Comment: You do not have to manually configure that env var. The startup script can figure it out by itself. Just download, unzip, and start

Comment: so I am supposed to delete the environment variables?

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to use the Linux (*.sh) scripts on Windows. That won't work.

Don't set (or unset) CATALINA_HOME. Tomcat will figure that out for itself.

Download, unpack, set JAVA_HOME and then call `catalina.bat start` or `startup.bat`
(they do the same thing - I prefer the former as it is more flexible if I want to do something slightly different).